# Optimising saving to an sqlite DB?

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an as3 app which utilises an sqlite db to save metrics data.  It is well known that as3 is single threaded, so when I save to this db, the Stage Video I am playing becomes jumpy!  I have heard that saving db data in batches can speed up this process so I save in a loop:

```
for (var i:int=0; i < metricsObject.metricsComponentData.length; i++){
    switch (metricsObject.metricsComponentData[i].mouseType) {
        case MetricsCollator.MOUSE_OVER:
            this._query_txt = "INSERT INTO " + this._tablePath[0] + " VALUES (null, " + this._sessionID + 
                                                                    ", " + metricsObject.metricsComponentData[i].timeStamp + 
                                                                    ", '" + metricsObject.metricsComponentData[i].component + "'" + ")";
                    break;
        case MetricsCollator.MOUSE_OUT:
            this._query_txt = "INSERT INTO " + this._tablePath[1] + " VALUES (null, " + this._sessionID + 
                                                                    ", " + metricsObject.metricsComponentData[i].timeStamp + 
                                                                    ", '" + metricsObject.metricsComponentData[i].component + "'" + ")";
                    break;
       } // end switch
    executeQuery(this._query_txt);
} // end loop
```

I have looked into pseudo threading examples but they all require a sprite or stage instance, the class I am executing this code in, is not a display class, I don't really want to pass an instance of the stage into this class, seems dirty! ;-)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most examples of pseudo threading use a display object and an enter frame listener, but you can just as well use a `Timer`, or if your application has some kind of update loop that works too.

Here's a simple example using a `Timer`:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class PseudoThreadExample extends Sprite {

        private var _timer:Timer;

        public function PseudoThreadExample(){
            // create a timer that runs with a low interval
            // tweak this to fit your needs!
            _timer = new Timer(30, 0);
            _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleTick);
        }

        public function startWorking():void {
            // put work to be done in list here
            // in your case that will probably mean making an array of SQL-
            // statements to run later
            _timer.start();
        }

        public function handleTick(event:TimerEvent):void {
            // pop a thing off the list and do it.
            // if list is empty, stop the timer
            _timer.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, make sure you're running your queries asynchronously, if not, execution will stop to wait for them to finish!

Comment: So may I clarify? would I need to invoke startWorking() from handleTick() to save to the DB in time increments, then once I am done stop the timer?  Therefore I would need to take the DB saving out of loops? Cheers for your quick response

Comment: No. You call startWorking from the outside, handleTick gets called by the timer until you stop it. This makes the "threading" transparent to the outside, you make your save call as you normally would and this spreads it out across time.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but video decoding is always done on a separate thread.